# Microsoft Task Scheduler's: Schtasks.exe unable to register new task in Arabic OS (locale)

Tags: command-line, windows-task-scheduler

I created a task in MS Task Scheduler app using simple xml command approach:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "TEST" /XML "C:\TEST.xml"
```

When I try to register the task in an Arabic regional OS setting/machine the task registration fails.

- Failed command_prompt (image):

[image]

XML (task):

```xml
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="...">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>1441-04-07T11:33:39</Date> 
    <URI>TEST</URI>  
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>1441-04-07T11:33:39-08:00</StartBoundary>
       ..
```

But, if I edit the date in this Xml to our default 2019 (en-US based calendar) instead of that Arabic (Hijri calendar) year 1441, the task registers successfully:

- Success command_prompt (image):

[image]

```xml
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="...">
      <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2019-04-12T11:33:39</Date>
        <URI>TEST</URI>    
      </RegistrationInfo>
      <Triggers>
        <TimeTrigger>
          <StartBoundary>2019-04-12T11:33:39-08:00</StartBoundary>
           ..
```

I am using this command from a Wpf UI application so I cannot put non-localized date format in it. Please let me know how to register this task in that localized machine! Thanks a lot.

Comment: What locale is Windows configured to use?  What calendar is Windows using?  Edit your question, do not submit commentary, when you provide this information.

Comment: [Your likely using the incorrect Task schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-schema)

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the reply. The windows is ar-DZ locale. I think arabic calendar is Hijri!

Comment: Why didn’t you edit your question?  Are you sure the DateTime string is properly formatted for your particular CultureInfo?

Comment: Which commentary, the xml tags you mean!? My xml is proper, i think, as it is working for all other locales (english calendars) except hebrew and arabic.

Comment: @Ramhound: I used dtNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK") as the Date/StartBoundary tag's value. This seems to be the problem as it is acts as an irrelevant year format for this locale/os.

Comment: Which is exactly what I asked.  Since I do not read or speak Arabic, your going to have to determine, what the proper CultureInfo format is exactly.  Isn’t Arabic and Hebrew Right to Left languages?  I would use DateTime.To*** methods using the appropriate calendar to determine what the proper format should be.

Comment: Yes, these languages are RTL. Its pretty tricky, at times, to debug them that way :-). I will try to do use the ToString overloads. Much thanks for your time.